# Different grunt tasks for watch and sass

Tags: javascript, css, sass, gruntjs, pug

I have a grunt project and I am using sass and jade together. I want to have a task for sass when developing where the style would be expanded for troubleshooting and a task for when I 'finish' the project and then the style would be compressed. I am new to grunt and don't know how to do it.

My gruntfile

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        jade: {
            compile: {
                options: {
                    pretty: true,
                    nospawn: false
                },

                files: {
                    'index.html' : 'src/index.jade'
                }
            }
        },

        sass: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    style: 'expanded',
                    nospawn: false
                },

                files: {
                    'build/css/app.css' : 'src/sass/app.sass'
                }
            }
        },

        watch: {
            jade: {
                files: 'src/**/*.jade',
                tasks: ['jade']
            },

            css: {
                files: 'src/sass/**/*.sass',
                tasks: ['sass']
            },

            options: {
                livereload: true,
                nospawn: false
            }
        },

        connect: {
            server: {
                options: {
                    port: 9000,
                    base: '.',
                    hostname: '0.0.0.0',
                    protocol: 'http',
                    livereload: true,
                    open: true
                }
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jade');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['connect', 'watch']);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get compressed css instead of expanded, you would first need to make another sass-task (so within `sass:{})`, call it `finish:` for instance and change the compression setting.

It should look something like this:

```
finish: {
   options: {
            style: 'compressed',
            nospawn: false
           },

   files: {
            'build/css/app.css' : 'src/sass/app.sass'
           }
}
```

Then after `grunt.registerTask('default', ['connect', 'watch']);` 
you can add another task, ie finish that should like:
`grunt.registerTask('finish', ['sass:finish']);`

To run it you would type `grunt finish` on the command line.

Comment: That's not it. I want to do something like grunt production where the sass would be expanded and grunt finish where sass would be compressed.

Comment: So I should make it like this: sass_fin: { dist: { options: { style: compressed....... } } } ?

Comment: Updated my answer again :/

Comment: Thank you, now i can use it more often and speed up my workflow.

Comment: Glad I could help! Cheers